# calculate height of none-binary tree

Tags: java, tree

How can I generalize the recursive code for finding the height of binary tree to non-binary trees? I checked [Non-binary tree height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476508/non-binary-tree-height). But there was just a pseudocode. So far I have wrote the following which is shooting me the wrong answer:

```
public static <MyType> int calculateHeight(MyTreeNode<MyType> r){
        if (r ==null)
            return -1;
        if (r.children.size()==0)
            return 0;
        int count=0;
        List<Integer> heights = new ArrayList<>(); 
        for (MyTreeNode<MyType> e : r.children)
            count = calculateHeight(e)+1;           
        heights.add(count);
        return max(heights);        
    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must not only include the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem, but also the desired behavior and a specific problem or error. _Not working_ is not a proper problem description. Please read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem of missing braces. You should add `count` to `heights` list for each of the children. You only added the `count` for the last child, which means you calculated the height of the right-most path in the tree (assuming the last child in your children list is the right-most child).

```
public static <MyType> int calculateHeight(MyTreeNode<MyType> r){
    if (r ==null)
        return 0;
    if (r.children.size()==0)
        return 1;
    int count=0;
    List<Integer> heights = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (MyTreeNode<MyType> e : r.children) {
        count = calculateHeight(e)+1;           
        heights.add(count);
    }
    return max(heights);        
}
```

Comment: Thanks. that was the problem.